Is Lowenheim-Skolem just an artifact of the formalism?
People here, and on various math blogs, love to point out the existence of countable models of ZFC. Seems like at least once a week, and this is stated like it has profound implications. Conclusions like "uncountable sets are an illusion," "God could count the reals," or "we might live in a model where every set is countable" are common.
But Cantor's argument shows, in a very generic way, whenever we conceive of a collection and its subcollections, there can be no one-to-one correspondence between them. The proof doesn't rely on any controversial axioms of a specific set theory. It's a basic consequence of a very general idea.
And sure, when formally studying models of a first-order set theory, some are countable from the metatheory. It's like making maps of the world. On any given map, South America will be larger than Europe, because it's larger in real life so we make maps that reflect that fact. But South America on one map might be smaller than Europe on a different map (because the whole map is smaller).
But so what? Why would you compare objects across models like that? It's common for diagonal arguments to relativize in this way. The halting problem: a Turing machine can't decide it's own halting, but there's always an oracle machine that can. Or the second incompleteness theorem: a theory can't prove itself consistent, but there's always a stronger theory that can.
Yet no one ever says "incompleteness is an illusion" or "we might live in a model where every problem is decidable." The fundamental ideas are reflected within each level, and comparisons across levels don't seem particularly important.
In physics, we encounter "artifacts of the formalism" sometimes. Like tachyons in special relativity, closed timelike curves in general relativity, or zero-point energy in quantum fields. Extra stuff that shows up in the math but generally isn't thought to be physically relevant.
Can we say the same about mathematical phenomena sometimes? Lowenheim-Skolem seems like a pretty good candidate. While the core idea behind |P(N)| > |N| is reflected (in some form) in each of the models of the set theories we use, the existence of countable models feels like a technical limitation of formal systems, similar to the various paradoxes that ensue when you have to use logic to talk about logic.
Thoughts? I'm sure there are some formalists here who disagree.

Incompleteness is explicitly a statement about formalisms, uncountability is explicitly a statement about models, they are not analogous. That "every problem is decidable" in the intended model is what every platonist says. |P(N)| > |N| relies on definability of cardinalities and powerset, which is not at all uncontroversial. It is the axiom that gives us uncountable cardinalities in the first place. Existence of Löwenheim-Skolem models is indeed an artifact of recursive formalism, but existence of uncountable cardinalities may well be another artifact of that formalism.

The assured countability of a model assuming there's infinite model of a first order theory assuming the said theory is consistent is a metatheoretic result which doesn't undermine the internal validity of uncountable sets within the said countable model unless you're strict constructive predicativist rejecting axiom of powerset of an arbitrary set. This internal validity goes same as incompleteness or halting problem, not affected by the famous 'paradox' of Lowenheim-Skolem which is indeed an artifact of first order formalism...

As Skolem himself noted that the definition of countability requires that a certain one-to-one correspondence between a set and the natural numbers and such correspondence itself is a set. Skolem resolved the paradox by concluding that such a set does not necessarily exist in a countable model, that is, countability is relative to a model, and cross model relativity in terms of countability cannot help the internal relativity. With full-semantics second order logic, you won't have LS theorems and such non-categorical 'paradox', but you'll lose the syntactic power of first order logic...

It’s not clear to me what the actual question is here. Are you asking whether or not Lowenheim-Skolem implies that every set (or indeed every model of ZFC) is “actually” countable?

On "similar to the various paradoxes that ensue when you have to use logic to talk about logic", I think there's something very direct about this connection!  We're talking about conceptions of Models and Modality here, and as a formalist, my contention is that the modality of semantic models is of formal, countable constructions of language and protocol more than of abstracta in themselves.  Lowenheim-Skolem tells us that we aren't missing anything important by taking this approach - there could well be uncountable sets, but our countable models of them will do the job just fine.

We can visualize ℕ as a series of hotel rooms in a row. Therefore that raises the question: what is ℝ? Is it basically the same as ℕ but with one mobile room you can't build a correspondence with, or is it qualitative different?


"In physics, we encounter 'artifacts of the formalism' sometimes.  ...
Extra stuff that shows up in the math but generally isn't thought to
be physically relevant."

Physicists have a criterion of relevance provided by the behavior of
physical systems that they seek to analyze.  Whether or not such a
system can be meaningfully spoken about in mathematics is one of the
many issues dependent upon the philosophy of the observer, such as
Platonism or Formalism.
A Platonist believes that such a system exists, and in particular that
cardinalities are real.  He would therefore interpret Lowenheim-Skolem
as an "artifact" or a weakness of first-order logic.  Note that, as
mentioned in the comments, Skolem was no Platonist, and held that such
phenomena illustrate the relativity of claims concerning cardinality.
A Formalist would view Lowenheim-Skolem as a profound result (that
tends to confirm the idea that infinitary entities possess no referent
in either the real or any putative Platonic realm), rather than an
"artifact".
I believe that, given the importance and routine use of countable
models in modern logic (they were used, for example, in the proof of
the conservativity of SPOT over ZF), the case of the Lowenheim-Skolem
phenomenon tends to be evidence against Platonism and in favor of
Formalism.
